# Angular2 Selector did not match any elements with bundle and ECM6

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a very simple angular2 project, configured to work with Gulp, Bundle and ECM6. Bundle will create a big file which contains the translated ECM5 of angular plus my app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 Test</title>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<mainapp>

</mainapp>
</body>
</html>
```

The angular app is defined as follows:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/core';

export class mainComponent {
    static get annotations() {
        return [
            new Component({
                selector: 'mainapp'
            }),
            new View({
                template: `<div>Hello!</div>`
            })
        ];
    }
}

bootstrap(mainComponent);
```

However when I load it, I keep on getting an error

```
"selector 'mainapp' did not match any element"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem was that I was including the `bundle.js` before the `mainapp` component was defined in the HTML. This fixed the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 Test</title>

</head>

<body>
<mainapp>

</mainapp>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:**

```
<script src="bundle.js" defer></script>
```

Seems to also solve the problem regardless of the order of the elements.

Comment: `defer` attribute added to the script would've helped as well.

Comment: You saved my day !! Thanks